# problem with the transparency

Tags: transparency

I'm fairly new on blender (and I'm using version 2.8).
I have a strange problem with the transparency of 2 objects. The geometries are identical but are imported from 2 different .obj files. How come they behave like this? Even if I combine them with CTRL + J it's the same thing.

I thank you for any help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check normals, doubled vertices, and possibly triangles to quads.

Normals: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> "outside".

Merge doubled vertices: Edit mode, select all, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> "by Distance".

Triangles to quads: Edit mode, select all, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Coby Randal.
Unfortunately I have already tried everything you are advising me. But it doesn't turn. The only thing that improves the situation a little is "erase only the faces" and "fill in the holes".
It's all today that I'm looking for Internet solutions, but without result. For this I tried to write a new post.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend so I can look at it? It sounds like you have bad geometry, like overlapping faces and edges. This likely either happened when exporting the obj or importing it. A quick fix could be the Remesh modifier, but I think you should find the root cause. I'd be happy to look at the file.